# java kdb - casting C to string

Tags: java, database, kdb

I am trying to cast `kx.c` class `flip` object to a string:

```
String test = (String) c.at(flip[0],1)
```

However I am getting an error stating that I cannot cast C objects to String. Does anyone know what I can cast a kx C object to return a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too sure what you mean exactly by "C objects" but I assume that it is a char array - the Java type to represent a Kdb string. Here is what you can do:

```
Object[] data = this.flip.y;
Object[] columnData = (Object[]) data[row];        
char[] data = (char[]) columnData[i];
return String.valueOf(data);
```

If you are trying to retrieve a kdb symbol then it will be a String array.

```
Object[] data = this.flip.y;
Object[] columnData = (Object[]) data[row];        
String data = (String) columnData[i];
return data;
```

Comment: Getting (left bracket)C  cannot cast to string when trying this

Comment: You will get [C error as you used the second algorithm - which is for retrieving a kdb symbol and not a kdb string. kdb symbol and strings are different so have different corresponding java types.

Answer (score 0):

A `c.Flip` is a mapping from keys to values.  In particular, it has `String` keys and `Object` values, stored in two arrays inside the `Flip` (called `x` and `y` respectively).

If you want to get the value for the key "foo", then you can do something like this:

```
c.Flip myFlip = ...; // Get hold of your flip
Object value = myFlip.at("foo"); // Throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if "foo" is not found
```

If you happen to know that the value will be a `String`, then you can cast it:

```
String strValue = (String) value; // Throws ClassCastException if value isn't a String
```

You can also combine the last two lines into one, like so:

```
String strValue = (String) myFlip.at("foo");
```